# Handling Intents Properly in wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

I am new to wit.ai and I have a basic question. I am trying to build a bot for handling queries on both cars and bikes. I have created an intent with car and have added some sample queries and trained the model to recognize the car intent. For example
1 - Top Sedan Cars
2 - Latest Hatchback Cars

But it does not scale to queries such as 
1 - Honda cars
2 - Ford cars etc

Even if I add Honda cars as a car intent pattern it does not scale to Ford cars. Is there a scalable way to handle such queries or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use composite entities to handle more complex query [composite entities](https://wit.ai/blog/2015/05/05/composite-entity) or you can have separate intents for company name and car types also to differentiate properly.

Comment: I believe composite/nested entities are deprecated as of now. At least this information shows up in the deprecated section of the docs.